# Setting update.autoCreateFields=false via API when creating Solr Cores for Sitecore 10.3

Tags: solr, content-search

I'm trying to Automate some of the Setup of Solr Core's for Sitecore 10.3 and everything works fine - apart from one thing which is that there is a requirement to set `update.autoCreateFields=false` in the `core.properties` file like so and I can't seem to get this to work via the API:

```
name=[CORE_NAME]
config=solrconfig.xml
update.autoCreateFields=false
dataDir=data
```

I tried setting it when creating the core but it seems to be ignored:

```
function Create-SolrCore($solrBaseUrl, $coreName) {
    $restUrl = "{0}/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name={1}&configSet={2}&dataDir=data&update.autoCreateFields=true" -f $solrBaseUrl, $coreName, $SolrConfigSetName
    Write-Host "Creating Solr core - $coreName : $restUrl ..."
    $result = Invoke-WebRequest $restUrl -Method GET -UseBasicParsing
    Write-Host "Created Solr core: $coreName. - $($result)"
}
```

I also tried like so using the set-user-property request but it still seems to have no affect:

```
 function Set-CoreProperty($solrBaseUrl, $coreName) {
    $restUrl = "{0}/collection/config" -f $solrBaseUrl, $coreName
    Write-Host "Setting Property for core - $coreName : $restUrl ..."
    $result = Invoke-WebRequest $restUrl -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body "{`"set-user-property`":{`"update.autoCreateFields`":true}}"
    Write-Host "Property set for Solr core: $coreName. - $($result)"
 }
```

Any input on how best to go about automating this would be appreciated.

I guess if it's not possible via the APIs I could set this in the solr.config file that is used by all my Core's and that should work? but I'd rather not have to make manual updates:

```
<!-- The update.autoCreateFields property can be turned to false to disable schemaless mode -->
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema" default="${update.autoCreateFields:true}"
       processor="uuid,remove-blank,field-name-mutating,parse-boolean,parse-long,parse-double,parse-date,add-schema-fields">
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

More info on the steps here:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/platform-administration-and-architecture/walkthrough--setting-up-solr.html

Answer (score 0):

When you utilize the API to set a user property, a `configoverlay.json` file is generated within the `conf` folder for the designated Solr collection. This file is responsible for housing and managing the property's value, without any alterations to the main `core.properties` file.

To confirm whether the property has been successfully updated, you can check the `configoverlay.json` file directly to view its content. Alternatively, you can access the following endpoint:

```
https://<host>:<post>/solr/<collection>/config/overlay
```

Comment: Thanks @surya I'll check that and see what the outcome is. I wasn't aware of this overlay approach.

Comment: @AdamSeabridge did you check it?

Comment: Hey, sorry I didn't as we decided to approach this in a different way on this project. When I get chance I will come back to this and test this approach though.